# Error using environment variable for email setting

Tags: config, emails, variable, environmentvariables, configuration

I'm trying to create an environment variable for email settings, but it doesn't work. Here is my email setting at config/general.php

```
'dev' => [
    '@host' => 'host',
    '@port' => '587',
    '@username' => 'user@user',
    '@password' => 'passwrod'
],
```

[image: This is my email setting]

I have also tried before to configure the email setting using this way at config/app.php, but it doesn't work.

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => function() {
        // Get the stored email settings
        $settings = Craft::$app->systemSettings->getEmailSettings();

        // Override the transport adapter class
        $settings->transportType = \craft\mail\transportadapters\Smtp::class;

        // Override the transport adapter settings
        $settings->transportSettings = [
            'host' => 'host',
            'port' => '587',
            'useAuthentication' => true,
            'username' => 'user@user',
            'password' => 'passwrod'
        ];

        return craft\helpers\MailerHelper::createMailer($settings);
    }
]
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting a few conventions mixed up.

Using an `@` is typically reserved for aliases https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/environments.html#using-aliases-in-control-panel-settings

What you're probably looking for is environment variables in your .env file.

You could set:

```
EMAIL_HOST=myhost
EMAIL_PORT=myport
EMAIL_USERNAME=myusername
EMAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Then from Settings->Email in the control panel, you can reference them with `$` https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/environments.html#control-panel-settings

```
$EMAIL_HOST
$EMAIL_PORT
$EMAIL_USERNAME
$EMAIL_PASSWORD
```